# Member functions comparison as predicates

Tags: c++, boost-bind

I have a structure like this.

```
struct A
{
  int someFun() const;
  int _value;
};
```

I store objects of this structure in a vector.

1. How to find the object whose member `someFun()` returns `42`?
2. How to find the object whose `_value` is `42`?

I guess I have to use the combination of `bind` and `equal_to`, but I'm not able to find the right syntax.

```
vector<A> va;
vector<A>::const_iterator val = find_if(va.begin(),va.end(),boost::bind(???,42));
```

**Edit:**

Thanks. But one more doubt.

What if I had `vector<A*>` or `vector<boost::shared_ptr<A> >`?

Comment: Do you have C++0x? A lambda would be the most readable solution.

Comment: Use Boost.Lambda or Boost.Phoenix. Or just define a function/functor.

Comment: For `vector< shared_ptr<A> >` simply dereference `_1`, i.e. `boost::bind(&A::someFun, *_1)`. For `vector<A*>` no change should be necessary.

Comment: @larsm. Thanks. `*_1` will work for any non boost smart pointer type(some class which overloads `operator *`) too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vector<A> va;

vector<A>::const_iterator v0 = find_if(
    va.begin()
    , va.end()
    , boost::bind(&A::someFun, _1) == 42 );

vector<A>::const_iterator v1 = find_if(
    va.begin()
    , va.end()
    , boost::bind(&A::_value, _1) == 42 );
```

In case you *do* need to compose bind expressions (e.g. using a `functor` that cannot be expressed with the operators supported by `boost::bind`):

```
vector<A>::const_iterator v1 = find_if(
    va.begin()
    , va.end()
    , boost::bind(functor(), boost::bind(&A::someFun, _1), 42) );
```

which results in a call to `functor::operator()` with arguments as follow: the result of calling the member on the argument to the bind expression, and 42.

Comment: `error: no match for 'operator==' in 'boost::bind [with R = int, T = A, A1 = boost::arg<1>](&A::someFun, (<unnamed>::_1, boost::arg<1>())) == 42'`

Comment: @balki What version of Boost?

Comment: BOOST_LIB_VERSION is 1_32 in my system.
I tried in ideone too but gives a different error. http://ideone.com/bnkz6

Comment: @balki Dereferencing the iterator returned by `find_if` yields an `A`, not an `int`. Fixing that makes it compile (have to change the next line, too). 1.32 is probably too old for this to work on your system however (I did not check the documentation though), you might want to try composing bind expressions (see my answer).

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I used `std::equal_to<int>()` for functor.

Comment: One more doubt. What if I had `A*`s in the vector instead of `A`?

Comment: @LucDanton let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1307/discussion-between-balki-and-luc-danton)